# XML Path not found in Selenium in namespace - tired all possibilities

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am running as part of a web testing program:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "*[@id=\"additionalTools\"]/ul/li[3]/a""))).click()
```

and it is not finding the element. All of my actions on the site work great with XPath.

The HTML of site is:

```
<div xmlns: actutil = "xalan://mataf.portal.utils.UserAccountUtil" xmlns: wsgut = "xalan://mataf.portal.utils.GeneralUtils" xmlns: wsnls = "xalan://mataf.portal.utils.MatafEnvUtil" xmlns: wspuma = "xalan://mataf.portal.utils.PumaServices" xmlns: wsportal = "xalan://mataf.portal.utils.GeneratePortalLink" id = "T05CHEAD_global" >
<div id = "PRIMARY-TITLE" class = "heading plus" >
<h1 aria-hidden = "true" role = "document" aria-label = "על מנת להפוך את האתר לנגיש לקורא מסך לחץ alt + 1. על מנת להפסיק הודעה זאת לחץ alt + 2." >
<span id = "tabTitle" style = "float: right;" dir = "ltr" > תיק מט"ח < /span >
</h1 >
<div id = "additionalTools" class = "tools" >
<ul class = "fll" >
<li class = "first" >
<a id = "personalNavigationFavorite" class = "favorite" title = "הוסף למועדפים" href = "javascript:matafTools.processFavorite();" aria-label = "על מנת להפוך את האתר לנגיש לקורא מסך לחץ alt + 1. על מנת להפסיק הודעה זאת לחץ alt + 2." > </a >
</li >
<li class = "li-calc" >
<a href = "javascript:matafTools.openCalc();" class = "calc" title = "מחשבון" aria-label = "על מנת להפוך את האתר לנגיש לקורא מסך לחץ alt + 1. על מנת להפסיק הודעה זאת לחץ alt + 2." > </a >
</li >
<li class = "li-save" >
<a class = "save" title = "שמירה" href = "javascript:matafTools.processSaveAs('031','html','', 'true');" aria-label = "על מנת להפוך את האתר לנגיש לקורא מסך לחץ alt + 1. על מנת להפסיק הודעה זאת לחץ alt + 2." > </a >
```

How can I find and `click` the save button? Searching by `class`, `full XPath` and `name` does not work.

Comment: Which a tag you want to click on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a wrong XPath expression.
Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='additionalTools']/ul/li[3]/a"))).click()
```

Or even this:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='save']"))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Why do I need div instead of * catch all?

Comment: You can use `*` there as well, but still your syntax was wrong. It could be `"//*[@id='additionalTools']/ul/li[3]/a"`

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the dynamic root with //?

Comment: Yes. Also redundant `"` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong in while waiting for element, correct syntax for explicit wait in python is :

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver,7).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "xpath")))
```

Now you can do:

```
element.click()
```

For your case:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver,7).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))

element.click();
```